# Laravel 5.6 - ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I recently upgraded my project to Laravel 5.6 and mysql to 5.7.21 and when I run migrations that were previously successful I am given this error.

**Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed.**

I spent most of the day researching so it would be great if you can give me a hint here.

Thank you!

**Error log**

```html
[2018-04-04 20:47:39] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. (SQL: ALTER TABLE sub_category_translations CHANGE placement_id sub_category_id INT NOT NULL) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 0A000): SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. (SQL: ALTER TABLE sub_category_translations CHANGE placement_id sub_category_id INT NOT NULL) at /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 0A000): SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. at /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:140, PDOException(code: 0A000): SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. at /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:138)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('ALTER TABLE sub...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(459): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('ALTER TABLE sub...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php(88): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->statement('ALTER TABLE sub...')
#3 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php(252): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint->build(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection), Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Grammars\\MySqlGrammar))
#4 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php(149): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Builder->build(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint))
#5 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Builder->table('sub_category_tr...', Object(Closure))
#6 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/database/migrations/2017_11_21_143155_rename_placements_table_to_sub_categories.php(25): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('table', Array)
#7 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(359): RenamePlacementsTableToSubCategories->up()
#8 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(366): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\{closure}()
#9 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(177): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->runMigration(Object(RenamePlacementsTableToSubCategories), 'up')
#10 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(146): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->runUp('/Users/andreeas...', 1, false)
#11 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(95): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->runPending(Array, Array)
#12 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(70): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->run(Array, Array)
#13 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
#14 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#16 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#17 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#18 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#19 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#20 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#21 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(865): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(241): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(143): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 {main}
"} 
[2018-04-04 20:47:39] local.INFO: QueryException: SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. (SQL: ALTER TABLE sub_category_translations CHANGE placement_id sub_category_id INT NOT NULL) in /Users/andreeastrattner/dev/valet-server/adwonce-v2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
```

Comment: in what table you get this error?

Comment: I get it in a migration I wrote long time ago where I rename a column and a foreign key,  I tried to dropForeign() before I rename but that doesn't help

Comment: can you add  whole error log ?

Comment: sure! - I added it to the main post. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: can you create new database and try to migrations again ?

Comment: already did - the error occurs on the first time I run the migrations on a fresh database

Comment: can I see the migrations table? how many migrations you have ?

Comment: I have 97 migrations and I run them all in one batch - what are your thoughts?

Comment: if you remove `ALTER TABLE sub_category_translations CHANGE placement_id sub_category_id INT NOT NULL` from your migrations dose it work?

Comment: 1846 error is relate to constraint

Comment: I won't be able to do that unfortunately as all my migrations are written with laravel shorthands like $table->renameColumn('column_name')

Comment: well then this kinda difficult, if you unable to solve this problem send me a zip file of migration and i'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine/DBAL 2.7 introduced a bug to the renameColumn() command, for now change your composer.json to

```
"doctrine/dbal": "2.6.3"
```

to downgrade your Doctrine version

Edit: For those still experience this issue, it was fixed in DBAL 2.7.1 so you can safely upgrade to that instead of downgrading to 2.6.3.